# Best practice for URLs of multi-language websites

Tags: url, multilingual, url-design

What is considered the best strategy for URLs of translated websites? Something I see happen frequently is:

```
http://example.com/english-slug.html
http://example.com/de/english-slug.html
http://example.com/fr/english-slug.html
```

This has the (minor) advantage that a user can manually switch to another language by modifying the URL. The disadvantage seems to be that the URL consists of a slug in the wrong language for every page not in the default language. That would cause a SEO penalty, I think.

The alternative would be to translate the slugs as well and optionally omit the language identifier as well:

```
http://example.com/english-slug.html
http://example.com/deutscher-slug.html
http://example.com/slug-francois.html
```

Some languages do not really lend themselves to be 'sluggified', such as Russian, Chinese and Arab. You'll end up with transliterations that make little sense.

Comment: I would go with the first option but without the work "english" in the filename. Here's a nice read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245655/seo-for-multilingual-sites-language-specific-results-without-changing-url

Comment: The word "English" is just there to illustrate that an English language slug will be used. So: substitute "english-slug" with any english slug, such as "hello-world". Same for "deutscher-slug" > "hallo-welt" and "slug-francois" > "bonjour-monde".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you should use language tags *and* translated slugs:

```
http://example.com/en/hello-world
http://example.com/de/hallo-welt
```

*Why language tags?* To avoid collisions.
Sometimes you might want to have the same slug for different languages (for example, "team" in English as well as in German).

*Why translated paths?* For better usability.
Not all users understand the "default" language, and depending on its script, they might not even be able to type/remember/dictate the slug. (It doesn’t make sense in the first place to use human-readable slugs that only part of your users are able to understand.)

Yes, it would be a "(minor) advantage that a user can manually switch to another language by modifying the URL". But it’s unlikely that users or search engines would *expect* this to work (see [my related answer on Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/48979/17633)). So you would gain little (URL hacking for advanced users) and lose much (bad usability for users using the non-default language).

That said, it would still be possible to enable this URL hacking feature in most cases: When users change the language tag `de` (in `/de/hallo-welt`) to `en` (`/en/hallo-welt`), you could check if it exists (if yes, show it), and if not, check if there exists a slug "hallo-welt" in any language, find its English translation and redirect to it (from `/en/hallo-welt` to `/en/hello-world`).

Comment: How to deal with homepage? (If primary lang is `en`) You don't want to have a same content on `example.com/` and `example.com/en/`... so? What do you recommend?
Redirect `example.com/` to `example.com/en`... or vice versa `example.com/en` to `example.com/` ? And with 302 or 301?

Comment: @MatějKříž: ([replied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38309154/should-default-language-of-multilingual-website-be-a-part-of-the-url/38363403?noredirect=1#comment101453631_38363403) to your comment on my other answer)

Answer (score 4):

Another way is setting the language as a query string parameter, such as:

http://example.com/hello-world?hl=en

http://example.com/hallo-welt?hl=de

for example Google Flights web site uses this method.

Comment: But using a parameters in the URL for SEO purpose in never recommended IMO

Comment: don't do this, not recommended by google itself. Link: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/managing-multi-regional-sites#locale-specific-urls

Answer (score 2):

The best solution, if you can afford it, is to send the document with the right name, that means, using the right word on each language.

Of course each document should be sent with the respective language setting on the headers.

For storing them, you can use folders and let the web server choose the right document according to the language preference; or you can use server side technology, like PHP, perl, etc to send the document and adjust the URL.

In any case, you have to have a default language to be sent when you don't have the requested language.

If you can't or don't want to send document with the right name, using subdomains is the best next option. This option, is not as common as adding the language after the domain, and that means, that people may not be used to it, although, it has some advantages, for instance;

- Each language behaves like a whole new URL/site (almost).
- People feel like visiting a dedicated site, not a subsection where the second language is relegated and may fail at any moment (some content may not be translated).
- Some people are not familiar with their two letter representation of language, but everybody knows how his language is called and spelled.
- It generates cleaner URL's.
- It is believed that having subdomains increases appearance on SERPs (I don't have knowledge of this and it may have changed).
- It's easier to have different layouts if you want to.
- It's easier to set different servers according to language.

Of course subdomains have some disadvantages, like:

- A bit more work to set properly from the server perspective.
- Less collaboration from the part towards high ranking.
- Some people may not expect it but expect a subfolder.

Next would be the subfolder option, as you show on the question. This is the recommended way if your main perspective is SEO since all the relevance of the domain stays on that same domain and each language helps to a common "pot" of ranking.

My perspective when choosing a solution, is never SEO, under any circumstance. Whatever ranking I get is due to the content itself and the best use I can give to technology. But I understand that my point ov view is not the most common.

One thing to consider also, is that you should provide some kind of explanation or help  the user so he can take actions to change to the preferred language. It may be using icons, a tooltip, or any other method that works for your design and verbosity.

One thing to avoid, and you didn't ask for it, but is related; is using language autodetection. Lots of times, the user is in a different country or using a version of a browser that has a different language from what he can understand and the autodetction just makes a big mess. Offer the default version and a clear way to change it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The server-side handling is not the problem at all. It is just a question of the best practice of the URL.
 
I cannot find reliable sources on this in regards to user experience and SEO. While you state that the latter option is preferred, you do not back it up with arguments or sources.
 
That leaves the question of ugly transliterations. Another thought would be that a search engine could infer the structure of translations through the subfolders. BTW, I believe that subdomains are generally *not* recommended for translations.

Comment: You are completely right, I didn't back my words with any study and that would be desirable. I'm only talking based on my experience with users, clients and servers, which is about 22 years, but still is just my opinion, so if I find something, I'll post it here. I'll add a bit more on my answer addressing your comments.

Comment: Thanks for expanding on your answer. It does make a lot of sense, both in putting user experience first and in going for subdomains. Concerning transliteration, it is more or less academic for my use case, but I added it since I was looking for best practice. Image a Chinese transliteration to resemble: http://example.com/cn/ni-hao-yin-hang.html. That would look alien to a Chinese and the same transliteration would be used for many words. I have noticed that Chinese blogs chose to opt for a [postid].html scheme instead.

Comment: I'll try to do a little research with my Chinese friends. I live in Asia for now. About the studies I was looking, all I found is SEO related, so I'll have to improve my Google-fu

Comment: I have mixed signals about subdomains and SEO. Subdomains are not recommended by moz best practices: https://moz.com/blog/15-seo-best-practices-for-structuring-urls