# URL structure for multi-language site

Tags: web, seo, multilingual, url-design

I want to make a multi-language site, but I'm not sure what the best way is to deal with the URL structure from a SEO point of view. Some examples:

**Product**

```
example.com/product/123/en/product-name
```

or

```
example.com/product/123/product-name/en
```

Or other?

**Category**

```
example.com/Category/en/furniture/chair/
```

or

```
example.com/Category/en/120/chair/
```

or

```
example.com/Category/en/chair/
```

Or other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Ignoring the SEO aspect, as it’s off-topic on Stack Overflow.)

Having the language tag as the **first** path segment is the most common convention. And it makes sense, especially if you [translate the path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27066060/1591669) (which you should!), because the path represents a hierarchy:

The top entry is the homepage:

- `example.org/en`
- `example.org/de`

From there, you select a product:

- `example.org/en/product/123/chair`
- `example.org/de/produkt/123/stuhl`

Or a category:

- `example.org/en/category/furniture`
- `example.org/de/kategorie/möbel`

If having the language tag somewhere in the middle or at the end of the path, it wouldn’t allow for [browsable URLs](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/55739/17633) (at least not in a sensible way, with translated paths).

Comment: ok, I'm so thank you. how about this:
 example.com/en/Category/furniture/chair/   or
 example.com/en/Category/furniture-chair/   or
 example.com/en/Category/chair/

Comment: @monabaharlou: Well, if "chair" is a sub-category of "furniture", `/category/furniture/chair` makes sense (so that you can also have `/category/furniture`). If there is no furniture category, you could go with `/category/chair`. I wouldn’t use `/category/furniture-chair` unless you really want the category to be named "furniture chair".