# URL structure for multilingual websites

Tags: url, seo, single-page-application, multilingual

I'm developing a SPA web app and it will support various languages. It is build with AngularJS and I am using angular-translate to provide i18n.

But I am struggling a little bit with how the URL structure should be. I do no plan on using either gTLDs nor ccTLDs, so that leaves me with three options.

- Use query params: `?locale=en-us`
- Use url paths: `/en-us/page`
- Store the chosen locale in localStorage or a cookie

The first option is a no-go according to Google's guidelines for web apps SEO. So that leaves me with the last two options.

I have a hard time deciding which is more beneficial, though I am inclined to believe that using url paths would probably be more crawler friendly.

P.S: Not sure if this is the best place to ask such a question either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second option is your safest bet as according to https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/59652/what-happens-if-i-try-to-set-a-cookie-on-a-bot cookies are ignored. You can test this yourself by going to the Google Console and fetching your website.

<strike>As of now most crawlers ignore cookies and DO NOT execute JavaScript. This means that they usually just download the html and make their judgements from there.</strike>

Some developers get around the no javascript problem by pre-rendering parts of their content. I haven't done it personally but you might want to check out https://prerender.io/

### Edit

As rolandjitsu mentioned google crawls and executes javascript content.

Comment: Actually, Google's crawler, is now able to execute JS. So is Bing from what I read. So they are able to index SPA apps without having to use tools like prerender.io or similar to serve content when `_escaped_fragment_` is part of the request URL. You can see Google's [deprecation](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification) notice for that.

Answer (score 1):

You should go with second option: provide the language tag (and, optionally, region subtags) in the URL path [as first segment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34088793/1591669).

For the simple reason that it allows you, visitors, and bots to *link* to specific translations.

Comment: Exactly, you don't want a link to show a different language based on a cookie. What language would you show to a new user?