# Google does not index my multi-language website

Tags: seo, google-search, meta, google-search-console, hreflang

We are about to officially launch Cleanfox : www.cleanfox.io

The issue that Google indexes the website only in English and when I look at the search results on Google.fr, the indexed content is in English.

I have gone through all the required stuff on both the Google Webmaster Console adding both FR and EN. I added hreflang attributes in both meta and  links (the two links that lead to another language)... But nothing happens, all the content is just indexed in English.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: Sorry I didn't know webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the same URL for both languages ([see answer with more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39169673/1591669)).

Furthermore, with `rel`-`alternate`+`hreflang` you should point to translations of the current document, but you always seem to point to `/en`/`/fr` (which then redirects to `/`). So for example, the following declaration on `https://www.cleanfox.io/forest` is wrong:

> ```
>    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="https://www.cleanfox.io/fr">
>    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://www.cleanfox.io/en">
> ```

Neither `/fr` nor `/en` is a translation of `/forest`.

Comment: I think I did all the changes but Google still says that I have href lang errors :(

Comment: @justberare: It seems that Google Search hasn’t yet indexed many of your English pages (currently only `/en/foxintel` and `/en/landing`). So you might need more patience :) You might also want to redirect the old URLs (with `301`) to new ones; currently they give 404. (Btw., I guess you don’t want `/en/landing` to get indexed in the first place, as it seems to have the same content as the homepage.) -- Also note that you can ask SEO questions on [webmasters.se] (asking for SEO advice, i.e., what is good/bad, is off-topic on Stack Overflow).

Answer (score 0):

for this you have create page for fr language so google will consider both are differnt page and will cr