# How to structure URLs to make a site available in different geographical areas and languages

Tags: multilingual

We have a site that will be made available in different geographical zones and on different languages. We envision making them available in the following URL

```
+--------+-----------+-------------+------------------+------------------+
| Locale |  Country  |   Region    |     Language     |       URL        |
+--------+-----------+-------------+------------------+------------------+
| nb-NO  | Norway    | Scandinavia | Norwegian Bokmål | company.no/      |
| en-NO  | Norway    | Scandinavia | English, UK      | company.no/no/en |
| lt-LT  | Lithuania | Baltikum    | Lithuanian       | company.no/lt/lt |
| en-LT  | Lithuania | Baltikum    | English, UK      | company.no/lt/en |
| en-SE  | Sweden    | Scandinavia | English, UK      | company.no/se/en |
| en-DK  | Denmark   | Scandinavia | English, UK      | company.no/da/en |
+--------+-----------+-------------+------------------+------------------+
```

I observe a lot of different approaches, for instance Ikea:

- https://www.ikea.com/no/no/
- https://www.ikea.com/se/sv/
- https://www.ikea.lt/en/
- https://www.ikea.lt/ru
- https://www.ikea.lt/lt

Some companies mix the `{location}/{language}` with different domains per location. Some again use the whole locale as part of the URL, as HM:

- https://www2.hm.com/no_no/index.html
- https://www2.hm.com/sv_se/index.html

Is there a best practice regarding this?

The question is somewhat related to [URL structure for multi-language site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34040042/url-structure-for-multi-language-site) but differs on whether to include full locale or not.

Comment: Combined language and region usually refers to the local variant of the language. For example, `en-GB` means "British English language, any region", not "American English language, UK region". If the language and region are independent variables, it would make sense to use the `/se/sv/`, `/se/en/` approach.